# regext copying second, third and fourth word

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th word from a file into another file, so far I know how to read a file and I have been trying different things but I don't get it right the code to get the words. This program will read the file.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

class PrintLines{
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner me = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("File Name: ");
    String s = me.next();
    File inFile = new File(s);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inFile);


    while(in.hasNextLine()){

        String line = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print(line + "\n");
    }
    in.close();
}
}
```

I have tried:

```
int i=0;
while(!Character.isDigit(in.charAt(i))){
i++;
}
```

to skip the first numbers, and then get the next three words, but I don't get it right:

986  Nasir  829  0.0040  Janine  1352  0.0069

I would appreciate any advice. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `String.split` method

```
String[] split = line.split(" "); // split by space
System.out.println(split[1] + split[2] + split[3]); // watch out for the array's bounds
```

Comment: @Bartg I wrote bad indexes - fixed now :)